# Bounded sequences in $L_{1}$ that has no weakly Cauchy subsequences

Tags: banach-spaces

Let $(x_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence in $B_{L_{1}}$ that has no weakly Cauchy subsequences. Here $B_{L_{1}}$ is the closed unit ball of $L_{1}$. By Rosenthal's $l_{1}$-theorem, the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ has a subsequence that is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{1}$. But I want a stronger result.

Question. Does the sequence $(x_{n})_{n}$ admit a subsequence that is $C$-equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{1}$? where $C$ is a universal constant.

Thank you!

Comment: Can't you use James' non-distortion theorem?

Comment: @TomekKania  Do you mean that if a sequence is equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{1}$, then it is $(1+\epsilon)$-equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{1}$?

Comment: Right, you wanted to have a subsequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is "No", and can be shown as follows. Let $\{e_i\}$ be a sequence which is $1$-equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$ and is contained in $L_1[0,1/2]$ (that is, functions are equal to $0$ on $[1/2,1]$). Let $\{f_i\}$ be a sequence which is $1$-equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_2$ and is contained in $L_1[1/2,1]$. For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$ consider the sequence $\{g_i^n\}$ given by $g_i^n=\frac1n\, e_i+\frac{n-1}n\,f_i$. It is clear that $\{g_i^n\}$ is $n$-equivalent to the unit vector basis of $\ell_1$, but passing to a subsequence does not improve the constant of equivalence.

Comment: Thanks, Mikhail. By James distortion theorem, we can only obtain a block basis $(u_{n})_{n}$ of $(x_{n})_{n}$ that is $(1+\epsilon)$-equivalent to the unit vector basis of $l_{1}$.

Comment: @Dongyang I am not sure: do you accept my answer or not?

Comment: I accept your answer. I am sorry to forget  to click.